# React hooks cannot push to array who's current value is all 0 i.e. [0,0,0]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using hooks to push a new value to an array in a certain context. The value is always a number, and my code works everytime unless the current array value is all zeroes. See the code below, in useEffect...I am trying to push a new value '0' to homeInningScores and awayInningScores under certain condition. This always works accept for one specific instance where homeInningScores and awayInningScores are both equal to [0,0,0] in which case it doesn't push anything.

```js
const initialState = {
  homeInningScores: [],
  awayInningScores: [],

  }
  
const [homeInningScores, setHomeInningScores] = useState(
    initialState.homeInningScores
  )
  
const [awayInningScores, setAwayInningScores] = useState(
    initialState.awayInningScores
  )
  
  
useEffect(() => {

    const isLeader = homeScore > awayScore || awayScore > homeScore

    if (currentInning > innings && homeScore && !isLeader) {
      
      setInnings(innings + 1)

      //This part correctly pushes to the array UNLESS homeInningScores or awayInningScores is [0,0,0]
      setHomeInningScores(homeInningScores => [...homeInningScores, 0])
      setAwayInningScores(awayInningScores => [...awayInningScores, 0])
    } 
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is coming from here:

```
if (currentInning > innings && homeScore && !isLeader) {
```

if homeScore = 0 then that is also evaluated to 'false' in javascript. You should check the homeScore == null or undefined or something like that. A number can evaluate to a boolean as 0 or 1.